# Apending the new data from the MainTable into existing table in the database

Tags: postgresql

There is Main Table called "maintable" which is updated every day and I created another table "subtable" subsetting the "maintable" from the query results. Both table has date column so now I want to append the new data that has been updated into maintable into subtable by running the same query but for only those days which "subtable" dosent have the days' data.

Sample query to create the subtable:

```
CREATE TABLE subtable
  AS ( SELECT date ,(sp-cp) AS pft FROM maintable
)
```

Now I want to run this query again so the data updated in the main table should updated in the subtable also and here I don’t want to drop the existing subtable  and create another instead I want to update the new results to subtable with only that data which is not present in subtable.

If I run the same query again it throws an error, saying the table already exists.

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results, as tabular text.

Comment: @GMB I edited with the sample example

Comment: @GMB please help

Comment: You might be looking for a materialised view. You can just `refresh` that.

Comment: I didnt get you @bergi

Comment: @VardhamanJain https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-creatematerializedview.html